# how to re-define routes for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to adapt a redmine plugin to new rails version (4).
Can somebody help me to convert the rules below to rails 4 format?

```
 match 'projects/:project_id/meetings/:action', :controller => 'meetings'
 match 'meetings/:action/:id', :controller => 'meetings'
 match 'projects/:id/meetings_settings/:action', :controller => 'meetings_settings'
```

Simply changing match to get (post) doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the **action**

It means after going to controller, what it should do next.

for that you must specify an action

```
match 'projects/:project_id/meetings/:action', :controller => 'meetings', :action => '??????????????'
```